# How to use mv command to move only selected files?

Tags: command-line, mv

What is the command to move the all files to target directory except `*.trg` files?

Tried the below command but it's not working:

```
mv !(*.trg) tgtdir
```

Comment: Do you have `extglob` enabled? Whats the output of `shopt extglob`?

Comment: Below is the output:

extglob         off

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 12):

You have an extended glob pattern, `!(*.trg)`, which will only work if the `extglob` shell option is enabled.

As the output of `shopt extglob` shows:

```
extglob off
```

you don't have the option enabled.

So you need to enable `extglob` by:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then your command should work.

Also, your command can be made more compact by:

```
mv -t tgtdir !(*.trg|tgtdir)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the below error msg:

mv: illegal option -- t
Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2
       mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1
       mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2

Comment: @Prasathraj Are you using Ubuntu? If so, which release?

Comment: What is the role of the `-t` option?

Comment: @A.L `-t` sets the target directory..

Answer (score 5):

Use `find` with a negated `-name` argument:

```
find . ! -name '*.trg' ! -name . -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} <tgtdir> \;
```

`! -name .` excludes current directory and `-maxdepth 1` assures only files and directories in the current one will be in the search results.

Just like with plain `mv`, depending on where your `tgtdir` exists you might need to exclude it too.